# how to get Number value form dictionary

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am accessing data from JSON and storing it in dictionary 1 and passing this dictionary 1 to another view controller's dictionary 2. The view controller has all the details mainly 12 labels. I have managed to access the strings but i am not able to get the number values. Please have a look at the code.

#### DetailsViewController

```
var dict2 = [String : AnyObject]()

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)       
    self.lblTopName.text = self.dict2["toponymName"] as? String
    self.lblFcodeName.text = self.dict2["fcodeName"] as? String
    self.lblName.text = self.dict2["name"] as? String
    self.lblCountryCode.text = self.dict2["countrycode"] as? String
    self.lblFCL.text = self.dict2["fcl"] as? String
    self.lblFclName.text = self.dict2["fclName"] as? String
    self.lblWikipedia.text = self.dict2["wikipedia"] as? String
    self.lblFcode.text = self.dict2["fcode"] as? String
    self.lblLongitude.text = self.dict2["lng"] as? String
```

Note. The last line of code that is longitude a number value. If I replace `String` with `NSNumber` it gives me the following error:

> Cannot assign value of type NSNumber to type String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plese try this if self.dict2["lng"] never null

```
 self.lblLongitude.text = (self.dict2["lng"] as! NSNumber).stringValue
```

else if can be null then

```
self.lblLongitude.text = self.dict2["lng"]?.description
```

Comment: Please note that this will cause the application to crash if for some reason `dict2` ends up without the `lng` key. Forced cast is to be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Forced cast should be avoided as much as possible, as it can lead to unexpected crashes. `(self.dict2["lng"] as! NSNumber)` will crash your application if for some reason the dictionary ends up without the `lng` key.

Your last line should be:

```
self.lblLongitude.text = self.dict2["lng"]?.description
```

This is guaranteed not to crash, as `description` exists on any object, and in case the dictionary somehow doesn't contain the "lng" key, you'll get a simple nil to assign to `text`.

Answer (score -1):

you can get integer value from dictionary like

```
int value = dict["integerValue"].integerValue // or doubleValue etc
```

and if you need string it can be like

```
self.lblLongitude.text = "\(self.dict2["lng"]. doubleValue)"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write like this

```
self.lblLongitude.text = String(format: "%f",self.dict2["lng"]!)
```